# GroupBy data with a specific column using Laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, laravel, group-by

I have the following two tables:

[image: Table Projet]    [image]

I'm tryin to get something like :

```
   adm_email1[
    
      nom_projet1
      nom_projet2
      ......
    ],
 adm_email2[
    
      nom_projet3
      nom_projet4
      ......
    ]
```

So I tried the following query usinh Laravel 8 :

```
$result = Projet::join('filiales','projets.id_filiale','=','filiales.id_filiale')->select('projets.nom_projet','filiales.adm_email')->groupBy('filiales.adm_email')->get();
```

But I don't get the result that I wanted.

If you have any idea please help.

**Update**

I'm getting the following result :

```
0 => App\Models\Projet{#1518 ▼
     "nom_projet" => "Orange"
     "adm_email" => "xxxx"
  1 => App\Models\Projet{#1502 ▼
      "nom_projet" => "iam"
      "adm_email" => "xxxxx"
```

Comment: please check my update

Comment: I think you want to use groupBy on the collection after getting the database records. Try `$result = Projet::join(...)->select(...)->get()->groupBy('adm_email');`